# Setting up Apache w/SSL using OpenSUSE / Yast

Tags: apache, ssl, opensuse

I have big problem when I try to setup SSL on my OpenSUSE desktop.

Generally, apache is listening on port 443, but when I try to go to

```
https://localhost
```

browser reports SSL problem: "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long". The same happens, when I try to go any of vhosts created on my machine (all my vhosts are ip-based)
I can fix the problem manually, by:

```
cd /etc/apache2/vhosts.d
cp vhost-ssl.template mySSL-host.conf
apache2ctl restart
```

That solves my https issue, but all vhosts are gone, and they all points to localhost.
When I restart YaST - vhosts reappears, but mySSL-host.conf file disappears, and https issue returns.

What is the proper way to setup SSL with vhosts using YaST, or at least how to make it compatibile with YaST?

Answer (score 0):

ssl_error_rx_record_too_long means misconfigured certificates.

Make sure you have proper SSL certificates installed in your system. 
HTTPS won't run without these. You get them from companies like startssl.com

make sure you have enabled the SSL flag:

(suse specific)

```
a2enflag SSL
a2disflag NOSSL
```

now let's look at an example config in /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/mysslhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        #  General setup for the virtual host
        DocumentRoot "/srv/www/mysite/"
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
        TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access_log
<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
</Directory>

 <Directory /srv/www/mysite/>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>


 SSLEngine on
 SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM  EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384  EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA 3DES RC4 !aNULL !eNULL  !LOW !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS +3DES 3DES +RC4 RC4"
 SSLHonorCipherOrder on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.nopassword.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.pem

#SSLUseStapling on
#SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
#SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off


 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>

</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
```

Then run rcapache2 restart